# Debian 10: No Bootable Devices

Tags: linux, debian, boot, grub, uefi

I am unable to boot into my new Debian 10 installation without using Super Grub Disk.

This is a brand new Debian 10 install on a fresh hard drive. I am not dual booting -- the Debian graphical installer wiped the drive. The computer is a Dell Percision 7810.

After the install, the computer rebooted and said there were no detectable bootable devices. I started by toggling typical settings like secure boot and legacy boot to no luck. I noticed the UEFI/BIOS configuration screen was able to detect a "debian" device and I could explore the EFI partition and see files like shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi. Once I went to boot from them, however, it would say there were no bootable devices again. I took a look at [some](https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/) [articles](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237568) [during](https://srvfail.com/ubuntu-bootable-device-uefi/) this process.

I eventually got the computer to boot using Super Grub Disk as mentioned in [this post](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-a-linux-pc-that-wont-boot/). Super Grub Disk was able to detect a number of options. I selected the first option, Linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 (hd2, gpt2).

Once booted, everything works fine. From here I've been trying to get the computer to boot without help from Super Grub Disk.

Since then I've tried:

1. Reinstalling GRUB as mentioned in [here](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi)
2. Converting my GPT partition table to a MBR partition table (and then back) since [this article](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160729/) said some UEFI/BIOS don't recognize GPT. I did this using the gdisk commands outlined [here](https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/convert-gpt-to-mbr-layout-in-any-linux-drives/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from/).

Below you'll see my partition table since I restored it to GPT:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name              Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32           EFI System        boot, esp
 2      538MB   181GB  181GB   ext4            Linux filesystem
 3      181GB   250GB  68.6GB  linux-swap(v1)  Linux swap
```

I'm sort of out of ideas. Any thoughts what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Just checking that you have run `grub-install /dev/sda` (for an appropriate value of `sda` that corresponds to the entire of your primary disk)?

Comment: I did. I will do it again now just be be sure though.

Comment: No dice. (Thanks for the suggestion though!)

Comment: maybe you have to whitelist the boot disk in the motherboard settings

Comment: Interesting update: I tried throwing Ubuntu 18.04 on the machine to see if it was me not configuring my UEFI/BIOS correctly, or if it was something about how Debian was installing GRUB. Ubuntu installed and boots fine out of the box. This means, I don't think I am missing whitelisting anything since I didn't have to for Ubuntu, and @GAD3R I don't think I need to install grub-legacy since Ubuntu is using an EFI version of GRUB to boot fine.
Obviously I'm missing something... evidence seems to imply Debian's default configuration is missing something Ubuntu is doing. Any thoughts? Thanks!